# Count unique rows of column in Array of object

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, object, unique

### Using

```
Ruby  1.9.3-p194  
Rails 3.2.8
```

Here's what I need.
Count the different human resources (human_resource_id) and divide this by the total number of assignments (assignment_id).
So, the answer for the dummy-data as given below should be:

#### 1.5 assignments per human resource

But I just don't know where to go anymore.
Here's what I tried:

**Table name:** Assignments

```
id       | human_resource_id | assignment_id | assignment_start_date | assignment_expected_end_date
80101780 | 20200132          | 80101780      | 2012-10-25            | 2012-10-31
80101300 | 20200132          | 80101300      | 2012-07-07            | 2012-07-31
80101308 | 21100066          | 80101308      | 2012-07-09            | 2012-07-17
```

At first I need to make a selection for the period I need to 'look' at. This is always from max a year ago.

```
a = Assignment.find(:all, :conditions => { :assignment_expected_end_date => (DateTime.now - 1.year)..DateTimenow })
=> [
#<Assignment id: 80101780, human_resource_id: "20200132", assignment_id: "80101780", assignment_start_date: "2012-10-25", assignment_expected_end_date: "2012-10-31">, 
#<Assignment id: 80101300, human_resource_id: "20200132", assignment_id: "80101300", assignment_start_date: "2012-07-07", assignment_expected_end_date: "2012-07-31">, 
#<Assignment id: 80101308, human_resource_id: "21100066", assignment_id: "80101308", assignment_start_date: "2012-07-09", assignment_expected_end_date: "2012-07-17">
]

foo = a.group_by(&:human_resource_id)
```

Now I got a beautiful 'Array of hash of object' and I just don't know what to do next.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to execute the request in SQL :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value('SELECT count(distinct human_resource_id) / count(distinct assignment_id) AS ratio FROM assignments');
```

Comment: This is great, my one thought it to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value instead of execute, to avoid having to work through a PGresult object.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I only think the date-range is missing I think? Where can I select the time-range, :assignment_expected_end_date => (DateTime.now - 1.year)..DateTime.now

Comment: @Kers add a `WHERE` clause to the select. You can copy/paste it from the console/log of your current request

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
human_resource_count = assignments.collect{|a| a.human_resource_id}.uniq.count
assignment_count = assignments.collect{|a| a.assignment_id}.uniq.count

result = human_resource_count/assignment_count
```

Comment: This will load the entire table in the rails app. I think `Assignment.select(:human_resource_id).uniq.count` and `Assignment.select(:assignment_id).uniq.count` would be better

Comment: Yes, though you could do Assignment.select(:human_resource_id, :assignment_id) and then use the lines I provided, which would avoid loading too much in memory and prevent multiple database calls.  Either way, your suggestion to do the whole thing in SQL is probably better, as it will be faster and won't load anything into rails memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the same question as for Baldrick, where can I input the DateTime-range for this selection?

Comment: In the case of my answer, you just use basically the same find statement you used in OP, with the addition of the select clause - `assignments = Assignment.find(:all, :select => [:human_resource_id, :assignment_id] :conditions => { :assignment_expected_end_date => (DateTime.now - 1.year)..DateTimenow })`.  In the case of Baldric's answer, you just have to add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement.  A quick google search should give you some good examples.